# What is the use of findViewById()

Tags: android-activity

I am new to Android development & I need sincere help from the experienced as I have loads of confusions and doubts.

Comment: Isn't it completely obvious by its name? You should try to explain your confusion as your question can be answered by just copy/pasting the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int))

> Look for a child view with the given id. If this view has the given
>   id, return this view.

So basically you need to pass an **ID** to the function and it will check the id. This will return the view that has the given id

Answer (score 1):

It will give a reference to a View

i. e.:

```
setContentView(R.layout.webview_page);
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
```

Will give you te ability of referencing the WebView you named myWebView in the xml layout you specified in the `setContentView()`

It requires that the WebView has been assigned a corresponding id attribute in the xml layout file:

```
android:id="@+id/myWebView"
```